# How in excel to find correct id number from list of different columns to compare to correct cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have for different, for example, languages same id and want to Vlookup or index, match or some other way to find correct translation row and to show corresponding id number from that row. I can do with 1 list but heres example with 3 languages.

How to find correct number for translation and getting correct number?

[image: Example]

Comment: You could just use `IfError()`, like `=IfError(Vlookup(C3;I2:J6;2;false);iferror(vlookup(C3;H2:J6;3;false),vlookup(c3;g2:j6;4;false)))` I think. It will first check for Latvian, then English, then German.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the **SUMPRODUCT function**:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((G2:I6=C2)*(J2:J6))
```

[image]

Note that **SUMPRODUCT function** cannot return strings. In order to return strings, I would use the **INDEX function**:

```
=INDEX($J$2:$J$6,SUMPRODUCT(($G$2:$I$6=C2)*ROW($J$2:$J$6))-1)
```

[image]

Comment: OMG, it works. WOW. I still dont understand why, but works for this. Maybe you will know also solution in case of 1 2 3 4 5 using a b c d e? @VBA Pete? Like susbstitute for each language type id?

Comment: Of course it works. I also updated my answer to reflect a solution for strings.

Comment: WOW. Cool. I was trying with index and match. Something like this isnt possible to fix to cover all 3 lists? Works only with one line but maybe possible to make it work for more? =INDEX($J$2:$J$6;MATCH(C2;$I$2:$I$6;0))

Comment: What do you mean by three lists? Range G2:I6?

Comment: Yes, doesnt work then index ;match Works only with 1 list not 3.

Comment: Strange, but hard to tell where the error is coming from as it works for me. If you wanted to use `index/match` you could do something like that: `=INDEX($J$2:$J$6,IFERROR(MATCH(D2,$G$2:$G$6,0),IFERROR(MATCH(D2,$H$2:$H$6,0),MATCH(D2,$I$2:$I$6,0))))`

Comment: This kind? =INDEX($J$2:$J$6;MATCH(C2;$G$2:$I$6;0)) For me doesnt. THis one is not possible?

Comment: No because you cannot use the match function in multiple columns at the same time.